# How do I zero out an SAS hard drive which is part of a Dot Hill array?

Tags: hard-drive, array, sas

I am helping a friend who has a Dot Hill Array (server?) and a full set of SAS drives that go with it.

The end goal is to zero out the drives so they can be re-used or sold. What I don't know... is where to start. Firstly how to connect to the array from a personal laptop. Secondly, does this need special software, or will the drives just appear as any other personal external hard drive?

Comment: SAS HDD are just like normal HDD (with SAS connector).. so as long as you can connect it to your laptop or PC (via USB or direct on SATA/SAS connector) you can run something like [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) to securely wipe it. Or if you can run DBAN directly on the storage array, it should do the same. Just take the HDD off any hardware raid and let DBAN works on the individual HDDs.

Answer (score 0):

That is a storage appliance. It should have management software that lets you interact with it. Best to check with the vendors website to see what management tools they provide.

If they don't provide any tools, then you need to connect to the appliance using iSCSI, NAS, or one of the supported protocols and format it from there.

Now, you can take out the drives and format them one by one (using an adapter to connect to your PC) if the first two methods don't work for you or you think that may be easier but depending on the number of drives, there could be 20,30, or more hard drives to wipe one by one. And doing a pass of 0s is going to take a long time. Efficiency wise, you'd be best to do it using one of the first two methods.

Comment: Very useful thanks. Don't have access to vendor software without purchasing it (doesn't seem efficient). iSCSI, NAS or other supported protocols sounds promising but beyond my knowledge and ability. I have 50 drives so whilst it may take a while individually, it's probably easiest for me to do. Which adapter would work best to connect to PC? They are Seagate Savvio 10K.6 HDDs.

Comment: Yeah then I'd recommend trying to connect to it via iSCSI or another supported protocol.

Comment: Ok. I will look more into iSCSI and how to do this.